# What is correct way to write?

Tags: possessives, numbers

What is correct : **72 hour or 72 hours**? In a article I have seen 72 hour rather than 72 hours.

Answer (score 1):

"72 hours" is correct, unless it precedes and modifies another word, as in the example of, "There was a 72-hour gap in the security footage," in which case it is hyphenated for clarity.